# CSS/JS are not loading in DXA 1.5

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5

I have changed the site mapping for localized sites using `Set-TtmMapping -RelativeUrl` [see my other question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/getting-error-while-running-the-set-ttmmapping-relativeurl) and re-published the pages and now site are working http://dxa.com/en the only issue which I'm facing now is CSS and JS are not loading. All the assets are available in file-system not published from CMS.

I have tried with `@WebRequestContext.Localization` and with other ways as well but no luck

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the URL path of your Publication (Mapping), you will have to ensure you republish the entire Publication.

Comment: i've re-published entire SG and after that when i hit `http://dxa.com/css/style.css` this give me `no matching localization found error` and when `http://dxa.com/en/css/style.css` its return 404 Page.  CSS path which is creating on view is `/css/style.css`.
Please suggest

Comment: Check the BINARY_VARIANTS table in your CD Content Store.

Comment: i have checked the `BINARYVARIANTS` table and all the URL now have `/en` as prefix is there anything i'm missing and that needs to check.

Comment: Is the URL path really `/en/css/style.css`?  DXA assumes that so-called Static Content Items have `/assets/` in their URL. For example: `/en/assets/css/style.css`.  Such URLs are handled by the StaticContentModule instead of the PageController.

Comment: We are not publishing the CSS/JS files from Tridion . CSS and JS files are available on file-system in root which is working before i created relative URL `/en`

Comment: Enable TRACE logging and check the DXA log file to see how your request is handled and when/where the 404 response is returned.

Comment: What is the Multimedia URL of your Publication, then? `css` ?

Comment: Image URL `/en/media/calculator_tcm6-273_w1024_h311_n.jpg` and there is no issue with images they are rendering as expected and CSS URL `/CSS/style.css` which we are giving in layout page Also tried with `/en/CSS/style.css` as well but same issue

Comment: Your CSS is neither part of the HTML Design (`/en/system/assets`) nor part of the media items (`/en/media`), so I would expect that the URL gets handled by the PageController instead of the StaticContentModule. The PageController will try to resolve it as a Page, which will fail. Again, check the TRACE log to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem previously, here are the steps that I have followed to resolve the issue

1. Publish Structure Information of the master site publication.
2. Publish Structure Information of the localized site publication.
3. Publish the Publish Settings page from both the publication and try.

Note: This is just a work around not a solution.

Hope it will help you to resolve the issue.